# can anyone guide me with how to upload geojson in metabase?

Tags: geojson

i am having trouble with uploading geojson to metabase
my geojson file is here

https://github.com/mohanrajanonymousallegator/anonymous/blob/master/india_states.json

when i try to load the data i am getting an error like this

Unable to parse resource at URL https://github.com/mohanrajanonymousallegator/anonymous/blob/master/india_states.json as JSON

can anyone help me with this issue
thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

Try validating the json with the link below, also let it fix it by ticking the "Fix JSON"-checkbox. Then redownload the file from there and try again with the new file (even if no errors were found). That worked for me in another case.

https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/